# Pyinstaller GLIBC_2.15 not found

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller

Generated an executable on Linux 32-bit Ubuntu 11 and tested it on a 32-bit Ubuntu 10 and it failed with a "GLIBC_2.15" not found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cyrhon FAQ section says:

> **Under Linux, I get runtime dynamic linker errors, related to libc. What should I do?**  The executable that PyInstaller builds is not
>   fully static, in that it still depends on the system libc. Under
>   Linux, the ABI of GLIBC is backward compatible, but not forward
>   compatible. So if you link against a newer GLIBC, you can't run the
>   resulting executable on an older system. The supplied binary
>   bootloader should work with older GLIBC. However, the libpython.so and
>   other dynamic libraries still depends on the newer GLIBC. The solution
>   is to compile the Python interpreter with its modules (and also
>   probably bootloader) on the oldest system you have around, so that it
>   gets linked with the oldest version of GLIBC.

and

> **How to get recent Python environment working on old Linux distribution?**  The issue is that Python and its modules has to be
>   compiled against older GLIBC. Another issue is that you probably want
>   to use latest Python features and on old Linux distributions there is
>   only available really old Python version (e.g. on Centos 5 is
>   available Python 2.4).